# Return unique_ptr<Derived> in function which is declared to return unique_ptr<Base>

Tags: c++

The code returns a `unique_ptr<Derived>` in function which is declared to return `unique_ptr<Base>`. I get an error when compiled with g++-4.8 but no error when compiled with g++-5.4 and g++-7. Is this a compiler bug with g++4.8 or have I done something wrong?

The code:

```
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
    Base() {}
};

class Derived: public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base() {}
};

std::unique_ptr<Base> func()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Derived> derivedPtr = std::unique_ptr<Derived>();
    return derivedPtr;
}

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> basePtr = func();

    return 0;
}
```

The error with g++-4.8:

```
$ g++-4.8 -std=c++11 test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ?std::unique_ptr<Base> func()?:
test.cpp:19:9: error: cannot bind ?std::unique_ptr<Derived>? lvalue to ?std::unique_ptr<Derived>&&?
  return derivedPtr;
         ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/memory:81:0,
                 from test.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:169:2: error:   initializing argument 1 of ?std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(std::unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&&) [with _Up = Derived; _Ep = std::default_delete<Derived>; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Tp = Base; _Dp = std::default_delete<Base>]?
  unique_ptr(unique_ptr<_Up, _Ep>&& __u) noexcept

  ^
```

No error with g++-7:

```
$ g++-7 -std=c++11 test.cpp
$
```

If I change `func` to `return std::move(derivedPtr);` then the code compiles on all the `g++` versions. Though I would like to understand whether my original code is valid or not.

Comment: New compilers come with new features, just use the new one?

Comment: It's never that simple is it? The real code base in question has been qualified with a specific compiler version and whilst an uplift is not impossible the process would be non-trivial. Regardless, I would like to understand whether the code is valid or not.

Comment: Just out of curiosity (luckily, I'm non-feline), what happens if you modify `func` to `return std::move(derivedPtr);`?

Comment: @AdrianMole Yes, that works with all versions of the compiler and is my current workaround.

Comment: @kaylum Have you considered trying a `std::shared_ptr<T>` instead?

Comment: [CWG1579](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1579)

Comment: @Ruks Thanks for that suggestion. I tried changing everything to `shared_ptr` and it compiled for all compilers. But somehow I feel that shouldn't be necessary as I'm not really wanting to have more than one copy of it.

Comment: @Jarod42 Wow, thanks. I was looking for such a reference but would have never found it on my own. So it does look like a bug or at least an incomplete feature.

Comment: Found in [return statement](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is [CWG 1579](https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1579) which applies retroactively to C++11, but old compiler versions might miss that.

Answer (score 3):

From the [status documentation of gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) for compiler features, you can tell that C++11 features were being implemented between gcc versions 4.3 through 4.8.1.

In fact the status page states:

> GCC 4.8.1 was the first feature-complete implementation of the 2011
>   C++ standard, previously known as C++0x.

Unfortunately there isn't such a handy page for the standard library implementation, but it *stands to reason* that the implementation of features in the library roughly parallels that of the language features in the compiler itself.

So, it is entirely reasonable that the version of the standard library in version 4.8 is not feature complete, just as the compiler wasn't.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that 4.8 falls into that gap. That explains a lot together with @jarod42's issue link.

Comment: Possibly related that `clang-cl` gives this warning on OP's *original* code: **warning : prior to the resolution of a defect report against ISO C++11, local variable 'derivedPtr' would have been copied despite being returned by name, due to its not matching the function return type ('unique_ptr<Base>' vs 'unique_ptr<Derived>') [-Wreturn-std-move-in-c++11]**.

Comment: See edit. The first feature complete version was 4.8.1 not 4.9. But still 4.8 is older than 4.8.1.